# Country or Region Specific Candidate Requirement

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The Location field in Careers filters the posting by the company location. For international job seekers the "Offers visa sponsorship" checkbox is useful, thanks for that.

However for remote jobs sometimes companies do have preferences about the location of the candidate. Can we add something to indicate employer's preferences about the location of the candidate?